# Turbolinks.visit not triggering on the same page

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, turbolinks

I have a page where we display embedded tableau dashboards and on the same page there is a dropdown using which which user can load different dashboards, on click of the dropdown options I call `Turbolinks.visit(url, {action: 'replace'})`

STEP 1: The first time user opens a dashboard the link will be
https://www.example.com/dashboards/56

STEP 2: The user clicks one of the dropdown options "My custom view" in the dropdown, `Turbolinks.visit` executes and the url will be https://www.example.com/dashboards/56?filter_id=12

STEP 3: The user can now interact with the dashboard apply different filters, which results in a totally different view from the view which was a result of STEP 2, **but this does not change the URL** but changes the view

STEP 4: The user now tries to click dropdown option "My custom view" again to go back to earlier version of view, but `Turbolinks.visit` does not open the URL as the URL did not change

My question is How do i force `Turbolink.visit(url, {action: replace})` to always visit the page even if its on the same page?

Any help in this would be great.

**Update 1:** I need to reload the same page using Turbolinks. the Turbolink.visit does not trigger if i provide the same page url, it does work if i provide a different url.

How can i use Turbolinks.visit to visit / reload the same page.

Comment: So the "change url via dropdown item" works (as described in step 2), but does not work after you used it once and the page/url changes, if I understand you correctly? If so, could you describe on how you initialize the dropdown behavior (links), and where you include the javascripts into your layout (header or footer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's working as expected, I had the below code which was preventing the reload on the same page

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:before-visit', function(event) {
            if (event.originalEvent.data.url == window.location.href) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
```